# How to generate random number in NetBeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, random, int, generated

I'm trying to generate a random between 1 and 100 in NetBeans, but what I used before in Eclipse isn't working. I can't seem to use Random, as it is underined in red: "cannot find symbol." Please show me how.

```
Random x = new Random();
int n = x.nextInt(100);//random number 1-100
```

Comment: have u imported java.util.Random?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use the fully qualified class name (or add an `import`). The `import` might look something like,

```
import java.util.Random;
```

while the fully qualified class name is [`java.util.Random`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) like

```
java.util.Random x = new java.util.Random();
```

Also, for a `number` in the range 1 - 100 you need

```
// int n = x.nextInt(100);//random number 1-100
int n = 1 + x.nextInt(100);
```

Because [`nextInt(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29) (per the Javadoc)

> Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive)

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you are missing the import:

```
import java.util.Random;
```

Answer (score 1):

For all errors like "`cannot find symbol.`", you can quickly hit `Ctrl + Shift + I` to import all missing library (in Eclipse it is `Ctrl + Shift + O`).
You also should search on the Internet for this error first, the answer everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

This is how to make it generate a random number, I know it is longer but its much easier to understand.

```
import java.util.Random;
class (INSERTCLASSNAME){
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Random random = new Random();
        int number;
        for(int counter=1; counter<=1;counter++){
        number = 1+random.nextInt(100);
        System.out.println(number);
        }
    }
}
```